# Customising Exchange 2010 Outlook Web App help links

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

Is it possible to modify Exchange 2010's Outlook Web App help links or their destinations (see the screenshot below)?:

[image]

They take the user off to pages on `http://help.outlook.com`, we don't want that and would like to direct users to our own internal help pages.

I am about to try rewriting the link destinations using IIS UrlRwriter or maybe a HttpModule, but I'd far rather be able to do this in an "officially supported" manner.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably as close to an officially supported method as you're going to get. I don't believe the article addresses changing items like the Help link, etc.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310750(EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: I had a good read through all the customisation docs but unfortunately it doesn't cover replacing help links. I have however managed to do this using UrlRewriter but at the cost of having to turn off compression. I may try a custom `HttpModule` now.